# Whenever I have two conflicting greater than how do I set a limit there

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm kind of new to programming. I used Game Maker before this so I need help.
Whenever I have two conflicting greater than how do I set a limit there. Example:
`if (weight>=20): (print(example)) 
if (weight>=30): (print(example))` So if I were to type in 35 it would print both things. So how do I make it print only one thing. Thank you for your time.
P.S I'm using python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the [elif statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

```
if x > a:
    # x is greater than a
    #do something
    pass
elif x > b:
    # x is not greater than a, but greater than b
    # do something
    pass
else:
    # do something else
    pass
```